# Why do I keep getting the same error while using AutoFill?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

While using AutoFill I get

"Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

The code I used came straight from recording a macro and works perfect:

```
Range("A158:A165").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A158:A165")
Range("A158:A165").Select
```

When I take this code and insert the values I need I am just faced with the same error over and over again

Here is the same code, slightly altered:

```
Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4)
Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4).Select
```

Here lastrow2 = row 116 (where the pattern of increasing numbers is) and lastrow4 = 118 (where I want the autofill to go to)

[image: Picture of the rows where the AutoFill is taking place]

Any explanation as to why I keep receiving this error and how to fix it?

Comment: @SJR I apologize, that was from when I was testing something else earlier. I have edited it to match my current situation.

Comment: @findwindow I apologize, that was from when I was testing something else earlier. I have edited it to match my current situation.

Comment: My turn to apologize. I read it as autofilter, not autofill. Let me look....

Comment: Change `Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4).Select` to `Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4-1).Select`

Comment: @findwindow I still received the same error using your suggestion.

Comment: Odd. Works fine for me. What about `Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4 - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & lastrow2 - 1 & ":A" & lastrow4)`? Remove the first line.

Comment: @findwindow Yes! Thank you very much, I finally stopped receiving the error and it works as expected